# Why are so many comments getting deleted now?

Tags: discussion

When did the mods decide to all of a sudden delete comments to the current degree? I get the idea that people don't like seeing answers in the comments but it seems a bit heavy handed as of late. I'd give examples but I can't as deleted comments are hidden from regular users(maybe even mods I'm not sure). Was there a policy change I'm not aware of? A moderator consensus? Something else?

I am not participating on this site daily at the moment, but quite a few of the comments I have left in the past few weeks have disappeared. I'm assuming moderator intervention.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what degree we're talking about, really, but the comment deletion volume is actually down in the last month versus previous ones. In fact, it's almost neck and neck with actual post deletion (usually a result of fly-by thank you or me too "answers"). However, comment deletion here is almost always a result of a flag on the comment and, typically, when that happens a few others will go with and I can't think of any recently that aren't hours or longer after the fact unless they're offensive.

It is worth remembering... https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment and noting that many of our comments here tend to fall into the *shouldn't* section of the guide.

However, while I still tend to be lighter here versus my other site, I have been cracking down on what Community Managers seem to want to call "answerments" or using comments to answer, especially on closed posts. Even then, though, most are still flag based and I only typically kill them when they're directly on the question rather than being an addendum to an answer. Nevertheless, even in that case, most people doing that have the ability to edit and answer and probably should. That's kind of the point of the editing ability.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Glad to hear it isn't trending upwards for some reason. The comment that triggered my question was one I made on the following (http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/66130/4892).  I asked why they assumed the effect was in post vs in camera. I thought it was a clarifying question and not an answer disguised as a comment. Now I see that the question has been edited slightly in relation to my question. I have that example from recent memory but I remember a few more times recently that a similar thing happened.

Comment: @dpollitt - There's no deleted comment from you on that question. Are you sure it's that one? Comments can be deleted when the post has been updated to reflect, but this question has only one comment historically and no edits.

Comment: Well that's tricky! I wonder if it is because I have primarily been using the iOS mobile app recently! User error or possible bug?! NICE. I definitely "thought" I commented there!

Comment: @dpollitt - nope, definitely not a comment and I generally leave that kind of one around until I can be sure a user has seen and responded or ignored.

Comment: Just to back Joanne up here, I do not see any deleted comments on that answer either. I think overall we (namely Joanne these days, every time I come here there is nothing to address from a moderation standpoint :P) are pretty light on deleting comments in general, and usually don't delete comments unless there has been a flag.

Comment: Yeah that's what I would have assumed too. Thx

Comment: Related http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/q/4655/27832?